# Change Image SRC on condition

Tags: jquery, image, conditional-statements, src

Hey guys, I'm trying to display an image depending on a variable that's in my HTML. Let me explain further...

I have this HTML

```
<div class="container">
<span class="var">1</span>
<img class="varimg" src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

And I want jQuery to analyse the span.var text, then if it is:

1: return "images/1.jpg"

2: return "images/2.jpg"

3: return "images/3.jpg"

(there will be only 3...)

and then inject it in the img src...

Is it possible ? I've been trying but I'm still a newbie in jQuery...

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.varimg').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('src','images/'+$(this).prev().text()+'.jpg');
});
```

put this code in your $(document).ready()

2nd edit: fixed it! click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vGKX9/) for a jsfiddle demo :)

Comment: Ok so I tried, and it does append the value to the src. The problem is that I have several "container", each one containing an image. so for now I have two, with the "var" = 1. It appends "images/11.jpg" for both of them... How can I tell jQuery to check for the appropriate "var" and append it to the appropriate image ?

Comment: OMG Thank you so much I can't believe I hadn't thought of that !

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
imgSrc = 'images/'+$(".var").text()+'.jpg');
$('.varimg').attr('src',imgSrc );
```

Comment: Yeah this would work also, but I would have the same problem as mentioned on the comment above... Thanks for replying so fast :)